# Is sample size affected by longitudinal vs cross-sectional design

Tags: sample-size

I am planning 2 studies:

1. Two groups are tested for their difference in blood sugar levels (a cross-sectional study)
2. One group is tested at baseline and again after 3 months for difference in blood sugar level (a longitudinal follow-up study)

The mean and standard deviation of expected difference is known and is same for both above planned studies.

Will sample size calculation for two studies be the same?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "mean and standard deviation of expected difference is known and is same" in the context of both designs. In the cross-sectional study you would be comparing the average in group 1 vs average in group 2, but most longitudinal studies calculate the differences within each individual and then take the average of those differences. Are you talking about the standard deviation of those differences?

Comment: For 2 separate groups, I would take difference with population variance as mentioned on https://select-statistics.co.uk/calculators/sample-size-calculator-two-means/

Comment: And what are you planning to do for the longitudinal study? The formula on that page isn't appropriate for paired data.

Comment: What formula should I use to find sample size of a longitudinal study?

Comment: This paper gives one method to find the sample size, https://www.jstor.org/stable/2533554. The calculations can be performed by the R package 'longpower'. There are also a few more references in that package you can look into.

Comment: But, if you're only considering the average difference in two time points, then a simpler method is to use a paired t-test. You can start reading here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paired_difference_test,  and google "paired t-test" for other resources

Comment: Thanks for explaining. However, I believe paired t-test is for only for analysis and not for sample size calculation. Why do you mention t-test here?

Comment: The sample size is determined by the type of analysis performed. This site has many questions about sample sizes for the paired t-test. https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=paired+t-test+sample+size